# Write two differential equations as an equivalent system of first order equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Write
>
> $y''+3sin(zy)+z'=cost$
>
> $z'''+z''+3y'+z'y=t$
>
> as an equivalent system of first order equations. What initial conditions must be given in order to specify an initial value problem?

My attempt was this:

$x_{1}=y,x_{2}=y',x_{3}=z,x_{4}=z',x_{5}=z'',x_{6}=z'''$

Then:

$x_{1}'=x_{2}$

$x_{2}'=y''=cost-3sin(x_{3}x_{1})-x_{4}$

$x_{3}'=x_{4}$

$x_{4}'=t-x_{6}-3x_{2}-x_{4}x_{1}$

$x_{5}'=x_{6}$

$x_{6}'=z''''$

The last one is strange to me. I feel like I am doing the substitution procedure wrong. Do I stop at $x_{5}$? Also, am I supposed to be using the same variables for both equations?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an $x_6$ because you can express $z'''$ in terms of the first variables $x_1, x_2,...,x_5$ and their derivatives.

Comment: Okay thanks, I made a system using $5$ new variables. May I ask how to specify the initial conditions to it? The system is $x_{1}'=x_{2},x_{2}'=cost-3sinx_{3}x_{1}-x_{4},x_{3}'=x_{4},x_{4}'=x_{5},x_{5}'=t-x_{3}+3x_{2}+x_{4}x_{1}$.

Comment: @numericalorange  For $y$ you  need $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$. For $z$ you need $z(0),z'(0),z''(0)$